Get dataframe from function into workspace
I've got a fairly simple function that contains a for loop converting specifically coded missing values to NA's:
make_na <- function(value, df){
  for(thisvar in names(df)){
    df[[thisvar]][df[[thisvar]] == value] <- NA
    num_NA <- length(df[[thisvar]][is.na(df[[thisvar]])])
    print(paste0(thisvar, " has ", num_NA, " NA's"))
  }  
  return(df)
} 

Running the function prints the modified data frame correctly, but I can't figure out how to get the data frame back into the workspace. I have also tried new_dat <-  return(df) in an attempt to assign the data frame to an object but that doesn't work either. Clearly there is something simple I am missing.

I think you can try df = make_na(value, df). The following is an example.
Names <- c("Jane", "Sam", "Jose", "Amy") 
Ages <- c(42, 33, 39, 25) 
Locations <- factor(c("West", "West", "South", "South"))

EmpData <- data.frame(Name=Names, Age=Ages, Location=Locations)

print(EmpData)

make_na <- function(value, df){
  for(thisvar in names(df)){
    df[[thisvar]][df[[thisvar]] == value] <- NA
    num_NA <- length(df[[thisvar]][is.na(df[[thisvar]])])
    print(paste0(thisvar, " has ", num_NA, " NA's"))
  }  
  return(df)
} 

df = make_na(33, EmpData)

print(df)

In this way, you can have the data frame with NA

I do not think we need explicit loops; try:
 X = data.frame(Name=c("Jane", "Sam", "Jose", "Amy"), Age=c(42, 33, 39, 25), 
                Location=c("West", "West", "South", "South"))
 
 insertNA = \(d0, x) {
   stopifnot(is.data.frame(d0))
   d0[d0 == x] = NA
   n = colSums(is.na(d0)); cn = colnames(d0)
   writeLines(paste(cn, "has", n, "NA's."), sep = "\n")
   cat("---------------------\n")
   d0
 }
 
 X = insertNA(X, 33)
#> Name has 0 NA's.
#> Age has 1 NA's.
#> Location has 0 NA's.
#> ---------------------
 X
#>   Name Age Location
#> 1 Jane  42     West
#> 2  Sam  NA     West
#> 3 Jose  39    South
#> 4  Amy  25    South

Overwrite X (in your case df) with X = insertNA(X, 33).
